# What are some examples of awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

What are some examples of awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?

Comment: For grammarians who don't want to strand prepositions, shouldn't the best sentence construction be: "About whom is this story?" :)

Comment: I haven't had this much fun with English since I don't know when. Thank you!

Comment: Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17478/analyzing-will-ferrells-i-thought-joke

Answer (score 72, accepted):

["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Comment: That is truly a bizarre sentence.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: in case wikipedia explodes and this site doesn't, and using "bison" as a substitute for buffalo the animal: Bison from the city of Buffalo which intimidate other bison from the city of Buffalo themselves intimidate other bison from the city of Buffalo.

Comment: Rather: Bison from the city of Buffalo which are intimidated by other bison from the city of Buffalo themselves intimidate other bison from the city of Buffalo.

Comment: @Midhat Well, when I wrote that snarky comment this site was in beta...

Comment: @Seamus, perhaps it is colour blindness.

Comment: A favorite of ESL students: "I saw a saw saw a saw."

Answer (score 41):

That that exists exists in that that that that exists exists in.

Comment: Nice — unlike the had-had sentence, this doesn't require any additional punctuation!

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this one

Comment: Brackets may help: (That that exists) exists in (that that (that that exists) exists in). [Or rewriting it, letting X stand for "that that exists": X exists in that that X exists in. X exists in whatever X exists in. X exists where it does.]

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: LISP-like English ftw!

Answer (score 27):

Jim opens a cafe selling fish and chips. He has a sign made. It arrives and it says "fishandchips". So he rings up the sign company and says:

```
You need to put more space between "fish" and "and" and "and" and "chips"
```

Comment: Or rather, he writes the company and says “You need to put more space between fish and and and and and chips” and they write back, saying “in your request, you need to put quotation marks between ‘fish’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘and’ and ‘chips’”.

Comment: And he writes back saying... oh never mind...

Answer (score 22):

[James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)

Comment: If you accept *Had* as a boy’s name... “In the English test, while Alice had had ‘had had’, Had had had ‘had’; had Had had ‘had had’, Had would have been correct.

Answer (score 21):

As far as awkward-*sounding* is concerned, I submit there are few sentences *spoken* in English that sound more awkward than:

Ed had edited it.

This is very hard to say in the rapid flow of conversation, and results in a sound something like:

Edədedədədit.

Try it for yourself, speaking quickly, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: A friend showed me a similar one, "Jiggle it a little, it'll open."

Comment: This reminds me of a (slightly dirty) joke: How do you titillate an ocelot?  Oscillate its tit a lot.

Comment: @Tesserex I like that! In Yorkshire, how do people say "It is not in the tin"? - Tin tin tin.

Answer (score 11):

> Ending a sentence with a preposition is something up with which we will not put.
> — [Someone who was not Winston Churchill](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html)

Comment: If you're going to attribute it to Churchill, please get the quotation right.

Comment: @moioci--If you're going to point out an error, please provide evidence that it's incorrect. I found this link: http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/churchill.html

Comment: Even though the quotation is apocryphal, the version you quoted is listed under "so scrambled it comes out backward" — the usual story has Churchill complaining about pedants insisting on not ending sentences with a preposition (and deliberately and ironically over-applying their rule), while your version has Churchill recommending the rule himself.

Comment: Oh BTW, I don't think this counts as a grammatically correct sentence; it's not grammatical to split "put up" like that.

Comment: This wasn't Churchill anyway. That's [a misattribution no longer to be put up with](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html).

Comment: What did you bring that story I don't like to be read to out of up for?

Answer (score 10):

In

> I found John in an unenviable position.

there are the syllables "an", "en", "in", "on", "un" (i.e. all of "aeiou") run together. This makes it a little tricky to say.

Answer (score 8):

How about some semantic awkwardness?

"Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" —[Noam Chomsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)

Comment: For grammatically correct meaningless sentences, I prefer Stephen Fry's sentence in his lovely ["Language" sketch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHQ2756cyD8): "Hold the newsreader's nose squarely, waiter, or friendly milk will countermand my trousers."

Comment: There is also the famous nonsense paragraph about "no soap" here: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1499950?uid=3737800&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=47698778664947

Comment: Also: "'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves..." (Jabberwocky)

Answer (score 7):

"[The horse raced past the barn fell.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)"

Comment: My favorite example of sentences that _seem_ difficult to parse

Answer (score 5):

The article you linked has a few other examples of such sentences. As it says, "Any word that is both an animate plural noun and a transitive verb will work."

Answer (score 5):

My grandfather's favorite is:

> What noise annoys an oyster?

Comment: Obviously, a noisy noise annoys an oyster.

Comment: Nose knows no snows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Who polices the police? Police police police police. Who polices the police police? Police police police police police police. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this one:

> Time times time times time squared equals time times time times time times time

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to put some punctuation in these:

- Wouldn't the sentence "I want to put a hyphen between the words Fish and and and and and Chips in my 'Fish and Chips' sign" have been clearer if quotation marks had been placed before Fish, and between Fish and and, and and and and, and and and and, and and and and, and and and and, and and and Chips, as well as after Chips?
- James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher.

Answer (score 1):

[That that is is that that is not is not is that it it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is)

Comment: This is not grammatical, as it is missing punctuation.