# Interesting sentences in English language

Tags: sentence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)

The following sentence is one eminent speaker

*"It is difficult to use, three times consecutively, in a sentence the word **because because because** is a conjunction" - C. N. Annadurai*

Please post the sentences that you found interesting