# "He thought that that might be awkward."

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, doubled-words

"He thought that that might be awkward."

I know this sentence is a bit awkward, but is it grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 6):

It may sound awkward, but it is grammatically **correct**.

The answers to this question exhibit more awkward ones: [Awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong, IMO, with re-wording the sentence if you feel it sounds awkward.  For example (with a context I provide):

> "Jim thought reprimanding her would be appropriate.  Bill, on the other hand, thought it might be awkward."  (The indefinite pronoun "it" replaces "reprimanding her.")