# I need help to see if this sentence is in correct format

Tags: grammar

> I suggest that that is the solution we propose.

I read this in a book and I'm not sure if there is supposed to be two thats. I've read it over and over again and I can't decide if it is correct or not. Someone help please.

Comment: It’s no different than “I suggest we go to the store” or “I suggest that we go to the store.”

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["He thought that that might be awkward."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/he-thought-that-that-might-be-awkward)

Comment: There is another question which [may help to answer this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem)

Comment: Consider "I suggest that this is the solution we propose."

Answer (score 1):

I would use it myself.

The first that refers to what they are about to tell you. The second refers to 'the solution' which they have just been discussing.

In informal speech, one that could be used and the same meaning would still be clear.