# Are there other repeated single word sentences like the Buffalo sentence?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)

My friend told me about the [Buffalo sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo):

> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo
>   buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

It is a grammatically valid sentence in the English language, used as an example of how homonyms and homophones can be used to create complicated linguistic constructs.

I was wondering if there are other examples of this type of sentence?

Comment: You are looking for this topic: ["Awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences).