# Words that can be repeated and still make sense

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there other repeated single word sentences like the Buffalo sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/are-there-other-repeated-single-word-sentences-like-the-buffalo-sentence)

Are there words in English like *had* that can be repeated while still making sense?
For example,

> The faith that he **had had, had had** an affect on his life.

Comment: related or duplicate? :http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2459/8183

Comment: Actually it's a duplicate of the first one. I already voted though...

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? The other question (somewhat) ANSWERS this question, but someone searching for this question will never find that one.

Comment: This question is asking for other types of this kind of sentence. [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences) clearly has many answers listing all the alternatives. That makes this a duplicate.

Comment: It is quite funny how this question has so many duplicates... :)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your good question! It is such a good question, it has been asked before, so your question has been closed as a duplicate. If you read that post and still don't feel that your question has been answered, then please feel free to edit this question to reflect what part of the answer in the duplicate you find confusing. If you have questions about why your post was closed, please leave a comment here or ask on [Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @KitΘδς: this really doesn’t seem like a duplicate to me; it actually seems a lot more interesting and on-topic than the old question.  That asks for whole *sentences* composed of repeated words — which are a cute puzzle, but rather contrived and little to do with actual usage.  This question just asks about words that can be repeated once consecutively within a sentence — and as answers so far show, there are quite a few different ways which this can occur within normal usage, which seems quite interesting, and quite distinct from both older questions mentioned.

Comment: @PLL I see your point about this question differing from the linked duplicates. However, I personally think this question should remain closed because it is too open-ended to be on-topic.

Answer (score 8):

*That that* occurs sometimes.  It sometimes means *that which*, and sometimes just *that that*, as in *I know that that will not work*.

Comment: +1: It also means *that that*, as in "He wanted a restful weekend, but John knew that that was no longer an option."

Answer (score 5):

There's a whole bunch of words that function as more than one part of speech (albeit with different pronunciations). You can probably construct acceptable phrases from some of these. Here are 3 that come to mind:

- to record record profits
- to address address problems
- to refuse refuse charges

Comment: Though of course these aren't literally repetitions of "the same word" (try pronouncing them).

Comment: @Neil. Agreed, I was cheating with my examples although I do pronounce 'address' (noun / verb) the same.

Interestingly, there's a post on  today's [Language Log] (http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3361 ) about the repetition of is, as in:
 
 I think the point is is that this is metaphor with teeth.

Comment: @Shoe: with a slightly different antecedent, that sentence might easily have been “I think the point is is that that is metaphor with teeth.” — a double is, followed by a double that.  New contrived-writing challenge: how many doubles in a row can you fit into a sentence? :-P

Answer (score 3):

One way this arises very simply and commonly is the repetition of adjectives and adverbs for emphasis:

> We were going really, really fast!

> I had a strange, strange dream last night.

On a different tack, there’s the interesting case of *What it is, is…*, discussed previously [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13056) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36683).

Comment: That that is is; that that is not is not.

Answer (score 2):

Another example is the word "buffalo", which is repeated eight times in the following sentence.

> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

Note that, according to the following Wikipedia link, it is a perfectly valid sentence.

[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

As for "had had", take a look at the following Wikipedia link.

[James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on 
 the teacher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)

Other linguistic examples of this sort are given in the following link.

[List of linguistic example sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences)