# Green green green green green. E-e-h?

Tags: meaning

Can this possibly be a correct phrase:

> Green green green green green.

I got it from [a Russian demotivator](http://cs540108.vk.me/c540104/v540104580/db8d/zm6fq4aAclE.jpg):

[image: weird cyrillic thing]

I wonder if there is *any* possible meaning, or whether it shouldn’t be more like this:

> Green green green**s** green green.

Comment: What does the Russian part say? It seems like a punch line

Comment: Which language is richer: Russian or English? There goes absolutely correct phrase 1 to 1 to Green x 5, but all words are different. And that is more readable than English version.

Comment: Translation is off topic, as is proofreading. Particularly proofreading the Intartubes.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/37837/14666

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either need a *greens* somewhere in that sentence, or you need to find a sense of *green* (without an *s*) as a countable, plural noun.

They should have gone for:

> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Answer (score 2):

One better translation is "green greenery greens green greenery". Poor Russians, they only know one English word for all this?! It is certainly easier to compete with a google translator than with original Nabokov in English! No wonder...