# What is the longest 1-word sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-patterns

I recently discovered the wonderful grammatically correct "[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)" sentence and I was curious if it is possible to construct a longer, but still grammatically correct, sentence using only one word?

- What if we allow bending the word any way we want, like tense,
  plural, etc. (e.g. "[Ducks ducks duck duck](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438476/what-does-ducks-ducks-duck-duck-mean)")?
- What if we also allow conjunctions ("but", "and", "or", etc.)?

Comment: *Police police police police police police police police*.

Comment: There are a few near duplicates of this, such as [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37827/words-that-can-be-repeated-and-still-make-sense/37837#37837) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/are-there-other-repeated-single-word-sentences-like-the-buffalo-sentence).

Comment: Also allowing those conjunctions effectively stops it being a sentence using only one word.