# What is the meaning of this sentence: "He can can a can"?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean? For me, it's more like "He is capable of opening a can," but according to some, it's not that simple. What does it exactly mean?

Comment: interesting sentence. voteUP !

Comment: A canner, exceedingly canny/ One morning remarked to his granny/ "A canner can can/Anything that he can/ But a canner can't can a can, can he?"

Comment: "Can" could also be the first name for a Turk, (properly pronounced like "John"), which could make this a real question: **"Can Can can a can?"**

Comment: This is making me feel like doing a Can-Can

Comment: See also [Awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)

Comment: Can you can a can in a can to can a can in a can to Can?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: Heh, can can can a can. Pretty impressive. ;o) Too bad I can't upvote this.

Comment: This would be much more impressive if the sentence were *“Can a can-can can can a canna can?”*  It fact, I dare say it may even lend itself to song: the song rhythm should of course be **♫ ♩♩♩ ♫  ♫ ♩** since you want the stressed words to be long and the unstressed ones short.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nice sentence playing with words!

The first "can" means "able to", or "He is able to can a can."
The second "can" is [defined:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/can)

> Slang . to throw (something) away.

The third "can" refers a container for storing food, rubbish, etc.

So, the sentence can be explained:

> He is able to throw away a container.

All, substituted with the word "can" for a humorous effect.

Comment: Nice explanation! So, I can use "can" now to throw things away?

Comment: Nah. Just can that expression!

Comment: I think it depends on whether you're using American English or British English. British English speakers rarely use "can" to signify "throw out". If this is a British English sentence, I would suggest the meaning "to put in a can".

Comment: Notice that can in a sense of throw away is slang

Comment: Surely it can also mean "to put something in a can", which is what is done at factories? So the sentence means "He is able to put a can in a can"

Comment: In American English, the second "can" could mean either "place in a can", or "throw away", based on context.

Comment: ... because "Trash Can" is "Rubbish Bin" in British English.  In BE, it would be He can bin a can.

Comment: Teensy additional, it might just be me and my context (Australian english), but I've also found 'can' being used as shorthand for 'cancel' - e.g: "let's can the meeting now, we're all in need of coffee", or "I'm going to can this process". Same base conceptual root as 'to throw out' mind you - the essence of terminating something. It's not hugely relevant to the sentence, but seeing as we're kicking around the various meanings of can..

Answer (score 8):

**can**

- is able
- to throw away
- container

Comment: so it means he is being able to throw away some containeR?

Comment: Yes, it means "He is able to throw away a container."

Answer (score 7):

"He can can a can" means:

> He can [is able to] can [place into a can or jar for storage or preservation] a can [a usually metal cylindrical container].

Comment: I think the second can is not referring to "canning". I think it is what @Unreason defined it, "to throw away".

Comment: @Trifle: It's one possible explanation. Also it can mean throw something away or fire someone or score a basket in basketball. Probably others as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/can) gives some slang definitions of *can*. Among them are

> 4.can - the fleshy part of the human body that you sit on; "he deserves a good kick in the butt"; "are you going to sit on your fanny and do nothing?"
>
> 5.can - a plumbing fixture for defecation and urination

Please derive the "not so simple" meaning of the title phrase yourself. Oh yeah, first "can" is really an "is able" version.

Answer (score 2):

A: Hello, what do you have here?
B: A can.
A: Pretty nice can you have.
B: Yeah...
A: And what is inside the can?
B: A can.
A: There is a can inside the can?
B: Yeah...
A: Sounds quite stupid to me. Who would can a can?
B: A can.
A: You mean... Some can canned a can inside the can?
B: Yeah...
A: I don't get it. How can can can...errr...
B: A can.
A: Yeah... Can can can a can?
B: Yeah...