# Term for sentences using multiple repeated words

Tags: terminology, repetition

Is there a term to describe the repeated usage of the same word in a sentence. Repetition is probably too broad for this, as it does not quite capture the deliberate and multiple nature of the repetition.

Some examples include

ELU favourite

> "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."
>   [(covered here)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31163/buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo)

and

> That that exists exists in that that that that exists exists in.
>
> James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher.
>
> Time times time times time squared equals time times time times time times time

Some of these were listed here [What are some examples of awkward sounding but grammatically correct sentences?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences)
but the question/answers don't refer to what this deliberate structure is called.

Murray Walker was always great for

> and and and and... he's into the barrier.

But I think that's slightly different.

Comment: Smartarsery? ;)

Comment: It could be argued that 'buffalo x 8' actually contains three different words. Or lexemes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, but those three words are being repeated. :)

Comment: Just pointing out that 'word' still needs defining :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You could be onto something. New question: "What is a word?"

Comment: I think that's the one that gets you banned for life. If I remember correctly, even 'lexeme', coined by David Crystal in about 1940, is used in different ways. 'Ship/s of the desert' is a lexeme according to some. _I_ use the term this way.

Answer (score 1):

The word that comes closest to describing this sort of behavior(repetition of the same word in a sentence) is: ***Epizeuxis***

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epizeuxis):

> In rhetoric, an **epizeuxis** is the *repetition of a word or phrase
>   in immediate succession*, for vehemence or emphasis.

Some examples provided(among others):

> - *"Never give in — never, never, never, never, in nothing great or small, large or petty, never give in except to convictions of honour
>     and good sense. Never yield to force; never yield to the apparently
>     overwhelming might of the enemy."* —Winston Churchill
> - *"O horror, horror, horror."* —Macbeth
> - *"Words, words, words."* —Hamlet
> - *"Rain, rain, rain, rain, rain."* —Guy Gavriel Kay
> - *"Developers, developers, developers, developers, developers, developers. Developers, developers, developers, developers,
>     developers, developers, developers, developers!"* —Steve Ballmer
> - *"Never, never, never, never, never!"* —King Lear
> - *"But you never know now do you now do you now do you."* —David Foster Wallace, Brief Interviews with Hideous Men

However, do note this in the definition of ***Epizeuxis***:

> for vehemence or emphasis

It appears this sort of repetition is usually done to emphasize some meaning. Accordingly, I'm not sure if a sentence like:

> That that exists exists in that that that that exists exists in.

would classify, without any further context.

But then again, upon reading the *answers in your cited EL&U questions*, it looks like these sentences **do make sense**. In that case, I would say "Epizeuxis" is indeed the word you're looking for.

Also take a look at Repetition [as defined on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device)). There seem to be some other types of repetitions which you might be interested in:

> - **Conduplicatio** is the repetition of a word in various places throughout a paragraph.
>
>   *"And the world said, 'Disarm, disclose, or face serious
>     consequences'—and therefore, we worked with the world, we worked to
>     make sure that Saddam Hussein heard the message of the world."(George
>     W. Bush)*
> - **Mesodiplosis** is the repetition of a word or phrase at the middle of every clause.
>
>   *"We are troubled on every side, yet not distressed; we are perplexed, but not in     despair; persecuted, but not forsaken; cast
>     down, but not destroyed..." (Second Epistle to the Corinthians)*
> - **Diacope** is a rhetorical term meaning uninterrupted repetition of a word, or repetition with only one or two words between each repeated
>     phrase.

Answer (score 1):

> "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo." (covered here)

In [The Etymologicon: A Circular Stroll through the Hidden Connections of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Etymologicon), author **Mark Forsyth** cites this very Buffalo sentence and the [Mandarin "Shi shi" poem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi_shi_shi_shi_shi) as examples of **Antanaclasis.**

According to Wikipedia, [Antanaclasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis) is:

> "... the literary trope in which a single word or phrase is repeated, but in two different senses."

[Merriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antanaclasis) of **antanaclasis** is similar:

> "the repetition of a word within a phrase or sentence in which the second occurrence utilizes a different and sometimes contrary meaning from the first."

Comment: This takes me back to a question I asked (poorly) years ago, concerning the example a certain TV channel used as an advertising slogan: _Channel ZPF D-Player ... making the unmissable unmissable_ [adjusted].