# I'm interested in finding a complicated sentence that has a very simple meaning

Tags: phrase-requests

If you know of any or can think of a complicated sentence that has a very simple meaning, please comment!

I want to use this as an example of why coming to terms with an author is important. And why it's silly to think that you can't understand something simply because it contains jargon.

Comment: Hello, Chris W, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I'm afraid that this question may not be a good match for our site because it asks potential answerers to identify example sentences based on rather vague and very subjective criteria. I wish I could advise you of a way to alter your question to make it more suitable for EL&U, but unfortunately I can't think of any. But perhaps others here will disagree with my assessment of your question.

Comment: I agree. Questioner is asking for something both loquacious (or periphrastic, if not downright circumlocutory) without being obfuscatory; therefore mere sesquipedalianism would not suffice, as OP inexplicably evinces obdurate fealty to the notion of facile decipherability of obtuse and esoteric argot.

Comment: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo. [Just use the site search](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/what-are-some-examples-of-awkward-sounding-but-grammatically-correct-sentences).

Comment: @RegDwigнt I wouldn't say the meaning of that "sentence" is simple....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A slight inclination of the cranium is as adequate as a spasmodic movement of one globular organ of sight, towards an equine quadruped utterly devoid of any visionary capacity.*

The answer is below

> ***A nod is as good as a wink to a blind horse***.

Comment: Funny! But we have to find a replacement for *optic*.

Comment: @DanBron according to Oxford Dictionaries Online it does exist as a noun, and one of its three meanings, albeit qualified as 'archaic' and 'humorous' is, believe it or not - *the eye*.

Comment: Highly questionable, WS2.

Comment: @LittleEva Do you think I should change *optic* to read *globular organ of sight*?

Comment: Indubitably, sir. Why use one word when four will do nicely!

Comment: -1 Just because a sentence refers to something common and everyday does not mean that the sentence itself has a simple meaning. Meaning ≠ reference